# Excel cells don't calculate until I double-click them

Tags: excel, talend

I have an excel sheet with three sum functions. The sheet is a template, so the rest of the sheet is blank, except for a couple text descriptions in Column A.

I use an ETL process (Talend Open Studio) to open the worksheet, input some data, append a couple other sheets, and save this different worksheet in a file share.

When I open the worksheet in the file share, the three cells with the sum functions show as zero, but when I double-click the cell, they calculate correctly.

I would like for the cells to show their calculation without me double-clicking them.

The cells are formatted as General, and the Calculation option is set to Automatic. What can I do?

Comment: are the formulas linked? or do they refer to data in the same workbook?

Answer (score 7):

select all, find-replace = with = and excel will see the contents as a formula.

Comment: Thanks! Been struggling with a Sage interface that drops out and doesn't refresh cells. Recalculate worksheet didn't work but this work around did!

Answer (score 4):

I have seen such problem occurs when exporting data from "NoSQL" databases such MongoDB, etc.

You can insert a column in right side and go to the "Data" tab -> "Text to Columns" option.

Make sure you select appropriate format while separating. 
Whatever you want to separate will shift to right side. Now delete this undesired column. You are done.

[image: Excel]

Comment: This option worked for me, though my problem is that the cell not showing the actual date value, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that Excel is seeing the cells as Text, despite the fact that you have formatted as General.  This can be the case when dealing with data coming from an ERP such as SAP.

Try these two approaches to see if one works:
Approach 1

1. Transfer your data to another sheet by Copying your data cells and paste special (values) into another sheet
2. Then copy and paste your formulas into the other sheet and see if that works.

Approach 2:

1. For all the cells you're having trouble with, enter formula `=Value([your cell])` in fresh column
2. Copy that column and Paste Special Values over it
3. Point your formulas to this new column

It's hard to reproduce the problem you're having unless you have a datasource that is exhibiting the issue.  But one of those approaches may help.

Answer (score 1):

How that idea worked for me:

Assumption: Source Data in Column A2

Data is "$4,238.74 "

In B2 = `RIGHT(A2, LEN(A2)-1)` to clear the leftmost and stubborn character ("$" that would not clear with find and replace)

In C2 = `LEFT(B2, LEN(B2)-1)`  to clear the rightmost and stubborn character (identified as unicode 160 that would not clear either)

After the above cleaning was done the cells still would not work with something as simple as `SUM()` without double clicking each cell manually.

Since that is not efficient User6574133's divide by 1 idea was applied:

In D2 = `C2/1` this called the stubborn (C2) cell that wouldn't calculate and created workable clean data in D2 that would calculate without having to double click each cell manually.

Answer (score 0):

In a blank column Put divide the same number by 1 (eg = 5.223/1 = 5.223) Problem solved

Comment: Your suggestion is really not clear - why would that help at all?  Does it have to be that number?  Does it need manually triggering?  More information please.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have calculations set to manual instead of automatic. To fix this, go to the Formula tab/Calculation/Calculation Options/tick Automatic.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed mine merely by going to formulas, calculation tab, "calculate now". It woke Excel up.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, go to Formulas, Calculation Options, and you will see it is set to MANUAL, change it to AUTOMATIC.  I believe some update must have changed it to Manual.

Comment: This is actually worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

I solved in a very simple way: try saving the file with OpenOffice.